# Dynamically add and delete a row from table & maintain hierarchy of table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my table I m filling the rows using an array.now the requirement of my app is
  User will be able to add or delete row.
second thing is there will be a hierarchy of table view, i.e ,on click of row the same table view should be reloaded with different contents related to that row.

what actually my requirement is user would be able to create folders,rename the folder ,move the content from one folder to another,delete the content of folder,delete the folder.

here the folder is row of a table.

anyone has any idea how to do this

Answer (score 0):

try inserting the below code at the index of row in the did selected method. for eg:
if(indexpath.row==0){
[self.tableView reloadData ];
}

Comment: its fine.but suppose I select a row and go to another table.again i select a row and go to next table and so on.since i m using the same array to fill the tables so how to maintain a track when I come back from one table to its previous one because the contents of the array

Comment: because the contents of the array is changed